# file.saveas in local (debug) mode getting "Not Rooted" Error. ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, localhost, server.mappath

Basic function: Users upload their (local) images to (remote) my website.

How to DEBUG while in local mode without getting "Not Rooted" Error?

I want to be able to save/edit/copy/move to the same directories on the web server.

While running on the server I am using Server.MapPath and this is pointing to the correct locations. I have all the right permissions to read/write in the directories.

So how do I point to the same directories without generating a "Not Rooted" error so I can debug locally and verify everything is working?

```
        if (upFile.HasFile)
        {
            string pathName = "";
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
                pathName = "http:\\\\www.website.com\\User_Data\\" + imgDir + "\\";
            else
                pathName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"/User_Data/" + imgDir + "/");

            string oldName = pathName + upFile.FileName;
            upFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(oldName);
        }
```

This generates the "Not Rooted" error while in local debug mode.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to map path from the root with `~`:

```
pathName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/User_Data/" + imgDir + "/");
```

Comment: Thanks Backs. The Server.MapPath is working while in active session. I am looking for how to point (use pathName) to those same directories while in debug mode.

Comment: Server.MapPath in debug mode points to "C:\mywebsite\User_Data" not "http:\\www.mywebsite\User_Data\ which is where I am storing and working on the images. Just don't want to have to publish, fix publish rinse and repeat over and over again. - Not even sure this is possible